Find the closest facet of the convex hull of some equidistant points
Let $m>n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $C_0, C_1, ..., C_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|C_k - C_0\| = r > 0$, i.e the points $C_1, ..., C_m$ are on a sphere centered in $C_0$. Assume that the convex hull of $C_1, ..., C_m$ is in such a way that every facet has at most $n$ points. Is there an algorithm of polynomial complexity to find the closest facet of the convex hull to the  point $C_0$?

I am surprised that "find the closest facet to a given point" is not of polynomial complexity with no assumptions whatsoever on the points whose convex hull we are taking! Could you point to a reference for this?

@diracdeltafunk provide a reference for what? That "find the closest facet to a given point" in the convex hull is not of polynomial complexity? Well, I do not know any polynomial algorithm for this ... I ask if anybody knows or if it is already known to be NP Complete (I do not know if it is even NP Hard: if someone gives the facet ... I do not know how to test if it is the correct one)
